# Ubuntu 18.04 Lagging, No Graphic Drivers Found

Tags: drivers, 18.04, graphics

I am new user for Linux OS, i just installed ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS few days back, Booting time and all are OK, but whenever i launch any App,the process is way to slow, and there is no proprietary drivers, i have installed Intel GPU tools 1.22-1 amd64 (though i am unsure whether it helps or not), my laptop details are below, kindly help me how to resolve this lagging problem, thanks.

```
Memory: 1.9 GiB
Processor : Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU T4500 @ 2.30GHz x 2
Graphics : Mobile Intel GM-45 Express Chipset
GNOME : 3.28.2
OS Type : 64-bit
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the computer information into your question!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Done. Thanks, Kindly tell me if there any other info is needed, i'll get them too.

Comment: GNOME is too heavy for this hardware. Consider to switch to loghter DE - Xfce or MATE. How much RAM do you have?

Comment: @N0rbert 2 GB, additionally 2 GB on swap partition.